# ¿Como puedo arreglar este error en mi html?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Estoy haciendo esta pagina web. Tengo una pagina diseñada para monitores (Pc Laptop Macbook !Mac) y otra para dispositivos moviles (Android y IOS) pero a la hora de cargar mi codigo html y css en el apartado de dispositivo movil lo carga pero el tamaño de la pagina es mayor al señalado en el css

[image: Imagen de error (Abierto desde android Samsung J8 2018)]

Mi pregunta es ¿Como puedo solucionar esto?

Mi codigo HTML es:

view-source:http://www.copinsa.com.mx/1/index-es.html

Mi codigo CSS es:

http://www.copinsa.com.mx/1/style_movil.css

Comment: Bienvenido seas, pudieras compartir tu código, de esta manera la comunidad sabrá desde que punto apoyarte

Comment: Mi codigo HTML es:

view-source:http://www.copinsa.com.mx/1/index-es.html

Mi codigo CSS es:

http://www.copinsa.com.mx/1/style_movil.css

Comment: @XxTavo16xX debes agregar tu código a la pregunta , para que a los demas usuario les sea facil ayudarte no adjuntar los links